# Why EF Core automatically load related entities when property referring to the entity is accessed in Select method of Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I accessing to referring property in the Select extension method of Linq, EF Core (5.21) automatically load (Join in SQL) this entity.

This test passes correctly, i.e. it means that EF automatically loads the property, regardless of the value of context.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled.

I tried to make the referring properties not virtual, it didn't help either.

Is it possible to disable autoload of referring properties in such cases?

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(false)]
[InlineData(true)]
public void IncludingAfterSelect(bool lazyLoadingEnabled)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext(_options))
    {
        context.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = lazyLoadingEnabled;

        var models = context.AddrGroupsObjects.Take(1);

        var modelsList = models.ToList();
        Assert.Single(modelsList);
        Assert.Null(modelsList[0].AgoAobj);

        var dtos = models.Select(x => new AddrGroupsObjectDto()
        {
            Id = x.AgoId,
            AddrObjectId = x.AgoAobjId,
            AddrObject = x.AgoAobj == null ? null : new AddrObjectDto() { AobjId = x.AgoAobj.AobjId }
        });

        var dtosList = dtos.ToList();

        Assert.Single(dtosList);
        Assert.NotNull(dtosList[0].AddrObject);

        modelsList = models.ToList();
        Assert.Single(modelsList);
        Assert.Null(modelsList[0].AgoAobj);

    }
}
```

Comment: `models` is still an `IQueryable`, and `Select` can load other related data without an explicit `.Include`

Comment: So you refer to an entity but you don't want it loaded. Like, wanting to know what the header of a word document is without opening the document.. 1) how do you expect EF will do this? 2) if you don't want the data why do you select it?

Answer (score 2):

No.  This is not Lazy Loading.  If you explicitly Select the entities they will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's what EF does. If you refer to related objects in the select or where it will join them so it can get to the data you've requested; they don't need an explicit Include

If it didn't then there would be problems all over the place, because it wouldn't be giving the code what the code had asked for.. unless you were earlier thinking that it's like SQL and Include is the equivalent of Join and if you don't Include then joins never happen.

But then, what would you expect EF would do in your case- you've particularly asked for x.SomeRelatedEntity.SomeProperty - should EF not load it because it should recognize that the property you've asked for is available in x as the other end of the relationship and use the x end value instead of the far end? Or should forgetting a join/include and trying to access related data cause a crash? This would miss one of the major selling points of EF (to hide the complexity of mapping an object graph to a relational database) and basically make all code full of something that is just like SQL with different keywords, so we might as well use SQL (or Dapper, so we get the object mapping part)

I'd recommend you change things so you don't refer to the object you don't want loaded i.e. `AddrObject = x.AgoAobj == null ? null : new AddrObjectDto() { AobjId = x.AgoAobjId }` - or omit this line entirely. You can work out how to treat the  AddrObject property entirely from AddrObjectId ID's value being null or not, after the query is over